# Javascript getElementById not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write plug-in for chrome browser. This code great work.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: "window.getSelection().toString();" },
    function (selection) {
        document.getElementById("txtID").value = selection[0];            
    });
```

After, I write this code for get input field value.

```
var value= document.getElementById("txtID").value;
```

But its not working value is null.

Thanks.

Comment: Check that you open the chrome debugger of the extension and not the one that belong to the open tab.

Comment: Callback function is not return any value. @chenop

Comment: First of all, check the value pass to getElementrById if its null. It should not be null. Check this stack overflow ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230095/getelementbyid-not-working-in-google-chrome-extension-for-embed. By placing timing it resolved the issue.

Comment: Where do you put your code? content scripts or background page? and where is "txtID" in? current web page or background page?

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem with the help of message passing.