# How can I change size on a website without getting "Cannot set property 'value' of null" error using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a browser automation program using html and Javascript for a website that has a "change size" select field. That field uses "s" as its ID. I tried putting the code in a one time use function or trying delays, but nothin works. In order to choose my size, I am using:

```
document.getElementById("s")['selectedIndex'] = 2;
```

When I run the code, it is able to change the size and go to checkout, but the code that I wrote for a check out form after the select size field does not get filled out. An example of that code to check out is below.

```
var email = "johndoe@gmail.com";    
document.getElementById('order_email').value = email;
```

When I remove the select size code however, the whole program works except for the size selection (Program simple goes through everything except size selection, keeps default). Is there any possible work around or something that I am doing wrong?

Edit:
The console says that: "(anonymous function), Cannot set property 'value' of null" I am running the script through a chrome extension, and a button triggers it (hence the html), the current function that I have been constantly changing for the size selection to work is:

```
var once = function() {
 if(once.done) return;
 console.log('Doing this once!');
 once.done = true;
 document.getElementById("s")['selectedIndex'] = 2;
};
once(); once();
```

I also have the form fill out function (part of the same javascript) in the same one and done function, using the code mentioned above for the form.

Im new to this.

Thank you!

Comment: check the server console for errors, and post more of your code here. we can't really help debug with just this.

Comment: it might help to provide more context. Please share your relevant html & javascript

Comment: I thought I knew what it was, but I tested and it works with the indexer and not quoting the value, so all I got left is, are you SURE "s" that's the id?

Comment: I have checked, and tried that again, but I still get the same error on chrome, "Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of null." Could it have anything to do with the Manifest or Chrome web extensions not running that code? These are current permissions:   "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]

Comment: is this running from an extension you're writing?

Comment: might be relevant, similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230095/getelementbyid-not-working-in-google-chrome-extension-for-embed

Comment: I am using a chrome extension. Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not using jquery that's another problem :(